# How does Omegle direct connect with HTTP Protocol?

Tags: php, ajax, http, tcp, xmlhttprequest

Every ajax chat tutorial ends the same.

You run a getChatMsg.php or some script every X milliseconds to check for new messages.

But not omegle.com they only send you a packet when you really need it not every X milliseconds.

For example I run every ajax chat tutorial i setup and sniff the packets I get a flow of getChatMsg or similar every second when I'm not even typing yet. Omegle handles it perfectly without using any external object like FLASH.

How do they do this direct connect? can anyone figure it out could you please help me out I've been trying to figure this out for weeks and i'm going crazy due to how much bandwidth it will waste doing it the current way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess they are using a [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) mechanism